# SVD decomposition and original matrix are not equal

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svd, scipy

When  l compute the SVD of my matrix **x** as defined in `kernel_hist_to_SVD()`. The resulted decomposition is not equal (approximatively) to the original matrix k. Here is my code.

```
def histogramIntersection(M, N):
    m = M.shape[0]
    n = N.shape[0]
    result = np.zeros((m,n))
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            temp = np.sum(np.minimum(M[i], N[j]))
            result[i][j] = temp
    return result


def kernel_hist_to_SVD():
    n=200
    d=2000
    x = np.random.rand(n, d)
    x=np.matrix(x)
    K=histogramIntersection(x,x)
    Phi, Lambda, PhiT=linalg.svd(K)
    ILambda=np.zeros(x.shape[0],x.shape[0])
    for i in np.arange(x.shape[0]):
            ILambda[i,i]= np.sqrt(Lambda[i])
    X2=Phi*ILambda
    X2=np.dot(X2, X2)
    y=linalg.norm(K-X2) # It is supposed to tend to 0. k approximately equals to X2
```

In `y=linalg.norm(K-X2)` l'm supposed to get a number which tends to 0, meaning that **K approximately equal X2**, however y is a very large number.

What's wrong around  ?

**EDIT-1**

```
def kernel_hist_to_SVD():
    n=200
    d=2000
    x = np.random.rand(n, d)
    x=np.matrix(x)
    K=histogramIntersection(x,x)
    U, Sigma, V=linalg.svd(K)
    # Testing 
    X2=np.dot(U, np.dot(Sigma, V))
    np.allclose(K,X2)
```

Comment: do you want us to debug your code?

Comment: You might do better on a Python specific site.

Comment: It is neither a debugging code nor a python problem

Comment: If it's not a debugging nor python problem, would you mind explaining how your code works for those of us that don't use python? Otherwise, please submit it to a python-specific site as @mdewey suggested.

Answer (score 3):

In your code you are assuming that the unitary matrices $U,V$ in the decomposition $K=U \Sigma V^{*}$ are equal. You should be testing with

```
X2 = np.dot(U, np.dot(Sigma, V))
```

(I used U,V instead of the misleading `Phi`, `PhiT`).

SVD is not Jordan decomposition. In particular, the dimensions of the square matrices $U,V$ can be different.

Comment: Thank you @Miguel. Please see my update. Not sure to understand the way of testing. Look at my updated function

Comment: Ooops, sorry, I meant to use Sigma, not K for testing!

Comment: Sigma is the lambda in my case. Let me update that

Comment: So we compare np.dot(U, np.dot(Sigma, V)) with  K (original matrix) using np.allclose(K,np.dot(U, np.dot(Sigma, V)) ) ?